# Realtime test execution aggregated report for selenium & nodejs

Tags: selenium-webdriver, report, real-time

I have a use case where in I have my JOBS which are running parallel in my CI pipeline. I wanted to see all the test cases results in a single report using selenium webdriver & nodejs...

We can utilize elastic search & kibana but I am looking for any other library which can serve this purpose.

Basically I want extent-report or allure-report but at aggregated report.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reportportal.io or when your tests run in parallel, pass a common directory where allure-results will be dumped from each stage/step and then using allure command line you can generate a single report. Alternatively if sharing a common NFS drive is not possible then artifact test results from each parallel execution and let your parent job fetch those tests artifacts from child jobs and then you can aggregate test results using any reporting tool